# How can i scale up my azure reserved virtual machine?

Tags: azure-virtual-machine

How can i scale up my azure reserved VM ? I am in a situation where I bought reserved instance per year for B2ms machine but after eight months I want to increase it to B4ms. How will payment look like in that situation. When number of vm is the same, but we need to scale it up ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could open up a support ticket to the Subscription and Billing team and request that you change the scope of the reserved instance. From there you could opt to have a larger tier and you would then be required to pay the difference between what you have already paid and what the new tier at that price would cost for the remaining of the contract.

You can just refer to [this official guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to raise a support ticket.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So if the VMs are in the same VM series, then also I would have to do the same ?

Comment: @Akanksha, welcome and yes, you have to do the same